# Pronoms toniques

Tags: pronoms

Est-ce qu'on peut utiliser les pronoms toniques pour les objets ?

Par exemple :

> Je suis vraiment attachée aux nouveaux moyens technologiques et je ne peux pas vivre sans **eux**.

Comment: Remarque: la phrase est parfaitement valide sans (eux).

Comment: Une alternative "neutre" aurait été *... et je ne peux pas vivre sans **ça***. Mais l'omission pure et simple comme proposée par iKiWiXz est tout-à-fait bonne également, et probablement plus courante.

Answer (score 4):

Votre phrase est tout à fait correcte.

*Eux* ou *elles* s'emploie comme pronom, que les noms qu'il représente soient des personnes, des objets ou des abstractions.

> La musique et la danse ? Je ne peux pas vivre sans elles !

Comment: Afin d'éviter une excessive charge émotive, on pourrait tout simplement dire "....je ne peux pas m'en passer!"